# viewController initial class set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers, a default `ViewController` and the one I added later for login: `LoginViewController`. I set `LoginViewController` as initial view. But when I run the app, after viewDidLoad in `LoginViewController` it fires `-viewDidLoad` in `ViewController` also. 
I have a modal segue, after login is successful to perform segue and show me the ViewController, that works. But in execution of app `ViewController` is also fired. Does anyone have an idea why this happens? AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
    { 
    // Override point for customization after application launch. 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"]; 
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: How do you set initial view? Do you use storyboards? Please paste here your view controller hierarchy

Comment: i checked initial view in storyboard and also in appdelegate i wrote this
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: Share the code of initialising view.

Comment: U could have simply ticked the option(Is initial View Controller) in your storyboard for your loginView and no need of this initialising code.

Comment: I did that also. But ViewController is also fired. :( At first ViewController was initial controller. maybe that is the reason, but I don't know how to disable it.

Comment: no disabling is required in storyboard only one view controller can be initial view controller. If you tick loginVC as initial then your other view controller won't be ticked. U can check this also.

Comment: I checked that also. I solved it. 
Solution was that LoginViewController was like this:
interface LoginViewController : ViewController <Delegates>
and i changed it to:
interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <Delegates>

Thank you.